# Toggle Div in Polymer 3

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer

I am trying to show and hide a div in Polymer 3 by clicking on the button. But when I console log the value of showhide boolean its showing undefined? My code is as below

```
static get properties() {
    return {
      showNotification: Boolean
    };
  }

connectedCallback() {
    super.connectedCallback();
    this.showNotification = false;
}

<div class='notification-count' on-click='_showHideNotification'> 
<div>4</div></div>
<div class="cards" hidden$='[[showNotification]]'></div>

_showHideNotification() {
    this.showNotification != this.showNotification;
    console.log(this.showNotification);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

To be sure the changes are notified you should use the set method, instead of directly assigning to the property. So your connectedCallback would be:

```
connectedCallback() {
    super.connectedCallback();
    this.set('showNotification', false);
}
```

and in your toggle function you have only an unused comparison, you're not even trying to change the value.. so maybe that would be:

```
_showHideNotification() {
    this.set('showNotification', !this.showNotification);
    console.log(this.showNotification);
}
```

I don't know the full logic of what you're doing there, maybe this is not a problem, but just keep in mind that you're calling the property *showNotification* and you're hiding something when it's value is true. So you might want to make sure you don't mean it the other way around..